# Can't use OpenCV 2.4.9 C++ API in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, opencv, mingw, codeblocks

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.9 in Windows and I used the .lib and .dll files I found in the folder **vc10** in Codeblocks. Although I had no problem using the old OpenCV C API, when I do something simple with the new API like:

```
Mat image;
```

I get an error that the functions called inside the Mat constructor can't be found. What may be causing this? I have included all libraries and all directories.

Comment: no, dear, you *can't* use the vc10 libs with mingw. you will have to build the opencv libs for mingw first, using cmake.

Comment: @berak Really? I had no problem with the C API so I thought that it's ok. Now I have to create a new question asking how to build the opencv libs for mingw because I followed every guide I found online and couldn't get it done.

Comment: I Think I followed [this without much hassle](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:q9A23TkwhlEJ:kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a). Also if you do post another question, don't forget to try it out first and post your actual error msg not just "How do I compile for MinGW innit"

Comment: @GPPK Your guide helped me build the libs. I had followed it in the past but I was missing one step and that's the reason I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer to this question (Not an Answer):**

no, dear, you can't use the vc10 libs with mingw. you will have to build the opencv libs for mingw first, using cmake. –  berak

**Follow up advice**

Compile the MinGW libraries following [this guide](http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/)